# Hadoop with php error : File /user/php81/admin/testsk3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: php, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have setup of hadoop on windows 7, the setup is i think all well, the command i execute are as follows.

```
$ bin/start-all.sh
```

which gives me output

```
starting namenode, logging to /home/admin/.ssh/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop-admin-namenode-php81.out
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: No error
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: No error
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/admin/.ssh/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop-admin-jobtracker-php81.out
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: No error
```

but when i copy a file to hdfs with following command

```
 bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal C:\\cygwin\\home\\admin\\books\\book1.txt testsk3
```

it gives me long error as

```
14/06/25 17:50:27 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/php81/admin/testsk3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:422)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:955)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:953)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:2937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:2819)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2000(DFSClient.java:2102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2288)

14/06/25 17:50:27 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
14/06/25 17:50:27 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/php81/admin/testsk3" - Aborting...
copyFromLocal: java.io.IOException: File /user/php81/admin/testsk3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
14/06/25 17:50:27 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /user/php81/admin/testsk3 : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/php81/admin/testsk3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:422)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:955)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:953)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/php81/admin/testsk3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:422)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:955)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:953)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:2937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:2819)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2000(DFSClient.java:2102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2288)
```

Comment: Which version are you using ? Did you try to run your cluster by running `sbin/start-dfs` and `sbin/start-yarn` ?

Comment: it's hadoop-0.20.2, I haven't used this both commands.

Comment: output of commands
$ bin/start-dfs.sh

namenode running as process 6492. Stop it first.
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: No error
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: No error

$ bin/start-yarn.sh
-bash: bin/start-yarn.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: It's `sbin`, not `bin`. Another basic question :), but did you format your namenode ? (`bin/hdfs namenode -format`)

Comment: It takes very long time to execute
bin/hadoop namenode